# How do I check if a 3D point is between 2 other 3D points?

Tags: geometry, 3d

How do I check if a 3D point is between 2 other 3D points? For example, if I had an imaginary line between two 3D points, how would I check if a point is on that line?

Comment: What do you mean by "having a line between two points?"  Do you have the equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the solution in your question already: *construct a line passing two points and check if the third point belongs to this line!*

You can find the line passing through two points (in any number of dimensions), by setting up a system of equations with one independent variable: all the points on the line are described by
$$ p(t) = p_1 + t (p_2 - p_1)$$
for some $t\in \mathbf R$. (Note, in particular, that $p_1 = p(0)$, $p_2 = p(1)$ and $p(1/2)$ is the midpoint between $p_1$ and $p_2$.

The question is now turned into: *is there a $t'$ such that a third point $p_3$ is $p(t')$?* This amounts to asking whether
$$ p_3 = p_1 + t(p_2 - p_1)$$
has a solution $t = t'$. We write out this in three dimensions:
$$\begin{cases} x_3 = x_1 + t (x_2 - x_1) \\ y_3 = y_1 + t (y_2 - y_1) \\ z_3 = z_1 + t(z_2 - z_1)\end{cases}$$

We solve for $t$ in each equation
$$\begin{cases} t = \frac{x_3 - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} \\
t = \frac{ y_3 - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} \\ t = \frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_2 - z_1}\end{cases}$$

So, the three points are aligned if 
$$\frac{x_3 - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{ y_3 - y_1}{y_2 - y_1}  = \frac{z_3 - z_1}{z_2 - z_1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with vectors, you could check whether C is aligned with A and B by finding whether the vectors $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{AB}$ are colinear.

In practice, if you have the coordinates $(x_A, y_A, z_A), (x_B, y_B, z_B), (x_c, y_c, z_C)$, then $\vec{AB} = (x_B-x_A,y_B-y_A,z_B-z_A)$ and $\vec{AC} = (x_c-x_A, y_C-y_A, z_C-z_A)$ are colinear if and only if $$\exists \alpha\in \mathbb{R},\vec{AC} = \alpha \vec{AB} $$

Also, if $\alpha \in [0, 1]$, you can see with a drawing that this means that C is between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can esily shift every thing, so one of the points are $(0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your points $A(a,b,c)$ and $X(x,y,z)$.

Then you have some vector $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ which is given by $X-A$ (component wise) which points from A to X.

Any point lying on the line connecting them is of the form $A+tv$, where $t$ is some real constant (stretching the vector based at $A$ and pointing to $X$)

If you can solve for some $t$ value then your point will be on the same line and if $0\leq t\leq 1$ your point will be between $A$ and $X$.